# Google model-viewer - how to set max zoom?

Tags: zooming, 3d-model, google-web-component

I'm very happy about what I'm able to do using Google [model-viewer](https://googlewebcomponents.github.io/model-viewer/). It's *relatively* configurable, but there's more I'd like to be able to do with the camera-- for instance, setting a max zoom/min distance from the target. I've found [code](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/model-viewer/blob/a336d62ee84968c0480be1bd46b71519ec894e2e/src/features/controls.ts) that seems to suggest how to modify this, but I don't know how to override the script delivered via the CDN. Is my only option to download using npm?

Excuse my naivete!

Answer (score 4):

You can see this issue [Zoom in/out #1172](https://github.com/google/model-viewer/issues/1172)

Now it's possible to use camera control settings:

- [max-camera-orbit](https://modelviewer.dev/docs/index.html#entrydocs-stagingandcameras-attributes-maxCameraOrbit)
- [min-camera-orbit](https://modelviewer.dev/docs/index.html#entrydocs-stagingandcameras-attributes-minCameraOrbit)
- [max-field-of-view](https://modelviewer.dev/docs/index.html#entrydocs-stagingandcameras-attributes-maxFieldOfView)
- [min-field-of-view](https://modelviewer.dev/docs/index.html#entrydocs-stagingandcameras-attributes-minFieldOfView)

```
model-viewer(
    src="https://cwervo.com/assets/3D-models/logo.glb" ios- 
    src="https://cwervo.com/assets/3D-models/logo-3m-scaled.usdz"
    auto-rotate 
    camera-controls 
    min-camera-orbit='auto auto 100%'
    max-camera-orbit='auto auto 100%'
    min-field-of-view='110deg'
    max-field-of-view='110deg'
)
```

Source: https://codepen.io/schmidtsonian/pen/VwvEwVw

Answer (score 3):

I'm the maintainer of the `<model-viewer>` project. You aren't crazy; we haven't added the ability to control this yet.

But don't worry! We are planning to add this feature to a release very soon (currently planned for v0.7.0). Please track https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/model-viewer/issues/458 for progress!

[edit] Also to answer your question about NPM: you *can* download the module from NPM and assemble a customized version of the pieces that make up `<model-viewer>`. Also, you could fork the project and patch it that way. I don't necessarily recommend these things, but they *are* options if you are desperate. If you go this route, I highly recommend asking questions on our Github project page. We are friendly and responsive to everyone.

Comment: Hi, when is this feature going to be released? Thanks!